# mysql select query missing a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like this

```
+---------+----------------+-------+------------+
| dept_id | parent_dept_id | level | name       |
+---------+----------------+-------+------------+
|       1 |              0 |     0 | Company    |
|       2 |              1 |     1 | HR         |
|       3 |              1 |     1 | Finance    |
|       4 |              1 |     1 | Operations |
|       5 |              4 |     2 | Sales      |
|       6 |              2 |     2 | Training   |
+---------+----------------+-------+------------+
```

I am trying to retrieve all departments and their parent departments. But what I also want is to retrieve the deprtment with ID 1. This guy is the top department and does not have a parent, all I want is a null in the department name.
So far I have this query

```
select
    d1.dept_id,
    d2.name as parent_name,
    d1.parent_dept_id,
    d1.level,
    d1.name
from
    tdept d1,
    tdept d2
where
    d1.parent_dept_id = d2.dept_id;
```

Currently, all departments get retrieved except for the top one, how can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you want the output look like? give us a sample.

Comment: @7alhashmi I just want dept_id, parent_name, parent_dept_id, level, name. parent_dept_id and parent_name can be NULL

Answer (score 4):

Try using the LEFT OUTER JOIN (The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.)

```
select
    d1.dept_id,
    d2.name as parent_name,
    d1.parent_dept_id,
    d1.level,
    d1.name
from tdept d1
Left outer join tdept d2
where  d1.parent_dept_id = d2.dept_id;
```

Comment: @Nademm_MK when I do this I get an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where d1.parent_dept_id = d2.dept_id' at line 9' in blahblahblah

Comment: If it works for you, you can select it as your answer. Sometimes answers are meant to give hints as we can't really test as we're don't have the same development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working, I did this:

```
select
    d1.dept_id,
    d2.name as parent_name,
    d1.parent_dept_id,
    d1.level,
    d1.name
from
    tdept d1 left outer join tdept d2 on d1.parent_dept_id = d2.dept_id;
```

Thanks  Nadeem_MK for putting me in the right direction

Crouz

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select
t1.dept_id,
t2.name,
t1.parent_dept_id,
t1.level,
t1.name
from tdept t1
Left outer join tdept t2
ON t1.parent_dept_id = t2.dept_id;
```